# Incorrect display Recaptcha and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, recaptcha

Using the theme "clean" of Recaptcha with IE9<, the input to enter captcha does not appear in  (#recaptcha_table > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2)), but is shown over again. How to display input correctly changing the css?

Comment: okay, I have checked reCaptcha and indeed, there is a problem in IE8

Comment: I'm trying to resolve this problem. Please stay online.

Comment: are you using Wordpress?

Comment: No, I include everything with echo recaptcha_get_html ($ publickey); Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Have you checked this? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization

Comment: I will post an answer within minutes

Comment: check my new answer!!! @user2568332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked and reCAPTCHA is not working in IE 8 from my end.

The simplest way to resolve this porblem is to create your own style of reCAPTCHA. So, is not necesarry to use the "clean" template from reCAPTCHA.

This code will show your reCAPTCHA (I have made a style similary to "clean"):

Check JSBin: http://jsbin.com/utubal/1/edit OR check below:

```
  <style>
  #recaptcha_widget {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  font-family: Calibri, Ubuntu Light, Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  }
  #recaptcha_widget a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2D7FC0;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
  #recaptcha_image {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
  #recaptcha_response_field {
  width: 300px;
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var RecaptchaOptions = {
      theme : 'custom',
      custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
  };
  </script>
  <div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">
  <div style="float:left; width: 80%;">
    <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>

    <span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above:</span>
    <span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear:</span>

    <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;"/>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
    <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">REFRESH</a></div>
    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">AUDIO</a></div>
    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">IMAGE</a></div>

    <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">Help</a></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY">
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY"
      height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
      value="manual_challenge">
  </noscript>
```

I hope this will help you!

PS.: Please remember to override YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY with your key (2 locations).